# Hyperplane tangent to a projective variety.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, projective-geometry

Let $X$ be a projective variety in projective space $P_n$. Let $H$ be a hyperplane, we say $H$ is tangent to $X$ at $p$ if $T_p(X)+T_p(H)\neq T_p(\mathbb{P}_N).$ 
My question is to prove a hyperplane $H$ doesnot vanish on $X$ then $H$ is tangent to a projective variety $X$ at $p$ iff $X\cap H$ is singular at $p$.

Any help would be appreciated. Also I am a beginner in algebraic geometry and do not know the language of schemes, so I would prefer an answer in the language of variety.

Comment: Huh?  Are you asserting a hyperplane is singular at every point?

Comment: I am asserting that the hyperplane section is singular at p

Comment: Take the case $X=H$.  Trivially $H$ is tangent to $H$ at every point $p\in H$, so you are asserting hyperplanes are singular at every point....

Comment: So you mean $H$ should intersect $X$ non trivially.

Comment: No.  More than that.  For a smooth subvariety there is always $\operatorname{codim}(X)$ independent tangent hyperplanes but $X$ doesn't need to be linear.  Take the twisted cubic, or the canonical nonhyperelliptic curve in characteristic 0, for example.

Comment: by non triviality i meant H does not vanish on X

Answer (score 0):

Up to a linear change of coordinates $(X_0: \dots : X_N)$ we can assume that $p=(1:0: \dots :0)$ and $H = \{ X_N =0 \} $ Since the problem is local we can restrict to the affine chart $\{X_0\neq 0 \}$. Suppose that $X\cap\{X_0\neq 0 \}$ is given by the zeros of $f_1, \dots, f_k \in \mathbb C[x_1, \dots , x_N]$ then 
$$
T_pX = \ker df_{1p} \cap \dots \cap\ker df_{kp} 
$$
By dimension reasons, $H$ is tangent to $X$ at $P$ iff $T_pX \subset T_pH = \ker dx_{Np}$ This translates to $\frac{\partial f_i}{\partial x_j}(p)= 0$ for every $i$ and $j< N$.

We have that $H\cap X\cap\{X_0\neq 0 \}$ is given by the vanishing of $g_i = f_i(x_1, \dots, x_{N-1}, 0)$, for $1\leq i \leq k$. Therefore $dg_{ip} = 0$ for every $i$ hence $H\cap X$ is singular at $p$.